# Extract 3 letters of Month and year from a Date column with different format using sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a column `Date1`

```
Date1

08-09-1998
11-10-1998
17-10-1999
23-09-1998
28-12-1997
```

The desired output I require is as follows

```
Date1

Sep-98
Oct-98
Oct-99
Sep-98
Dec-97
```

Help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Is Date1 a date field or a text field?

Comment: Step 1. Store dates using a date data type. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It is a text field @Kevin

Comment: but I would like to know how to do it if it is date as well as text field @Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%b-%y') AS Displaydate  from test
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5814fb46bbdda0b7eba6aa2c4afac8c1)

If it is a varchar :

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%b-%y') AS Displaydate  from test
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d1c85e10cc27cac373efbb080aa4bb7) for both situations.

Because OP changed the databse info here is a **solution for SQLServer** for data type date:

```
SELECT concat( FORMAT([date_col], 'MMM', 'en-US'), '-', YEAR( date_col ) % 100) 
from test
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87276d901a58658858dbf6ee12b25215)

And here is the solution for varchar data type:

```
SELECT concat( FORMAT([date_col], 'MMM', 'en-US'), '-', YEAR( date_col ) % 100)
, concat( FORMAT(convert(date, var_col, 105), 'MMM', 'en-US'), '-', YEAR( date_col ) % 100) 
from test
```

[Here is the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=545db824a54c71995cc3fc774ccf1890) for both options.

Comment: 'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. Suddenly I am facing this error. Can you also help me out with this please? @VBoka

Comment: You use MySQL ? Which version ?

Comment: select @@VERSION
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41 (X64)   Oct 28 2019 19:56:59   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition @VBoka

Comment: So you are not using MySQL as it is tagged in your question.

Comment: You can do two things: 1. Open a new question or 2. remove mark from my answer that it is correct and edit your question with the correct tag. Your tag should be SQLServer and not MySQL. Of course this will not work, it is not the same database

Comment: It worked but I got another problem that my dates are being converted to yyyy-dd-mm format so suppose if i convert 2020-02-03 it will give me answer as Feb-20 instead of Mar-20. I am feeding the values as dd-mm-yyyy but it automatically get converted to yyyy-dd-mm format, can you help me with this please. your work is appreciated brother. @VBoka

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209553/discussion-between-aniket-rele-and-vboka).